# How do I reference a row using multiple properties in the current entity?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I need to reference a row in a table not by its primary key but by two other columns.  How do I configure that in fluent-nhibernate?

I am using FluentNHibernate 1.3

Example:  If the other table YY has columns foo and bar (assume datatype is integer if that helps) which are *not* primary keys.  My current class XX has those properties and I want to reference a YY object from XX.  Should I put the following in the `ClassMap<XX>` class  if the local member is YYObject and the fields to reference it are XX.foo and XX.bar ?

```
CompositeId(x => x.YYObject).KeyProperty(x => x.foo).KeyProperty(x => x.bar);
```

I am also not quite sure how the `ClassMap<YY>` class should be adjusted accordingly. If you have done such things we could use some guidance.

We are dealing with a legacy situation so I cannot wave my hands and make it all go away.

Answer (score 0):

if possible define a Component around the two properties

```
Component(x => x.Comp, c =>
{
    c.Map(x => x.Foo);
    c.Map(x => x.Bar);
});
```

and reference it

```
References(x => x.ParentObject)
    .KeyColumns.Add("parent_foo", "parent_bar");
    .PropertyRef(p => p.Comp);
```